# While loop with if statement

Tags: python, while-loop

I am combining a while-loop with an if-statement to add a number from 0-24 if the number is even. I constantly go to an infinite loop.

```
 number = range(0,50)
 i = 0
 total = 0

 while number[i]<25:
     if number[i]%2==0:
         total+=number[i]
         i+=1
     print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are adding 1 to i inside the if statement.
You could simplify your code like this:

```py
total = 0
for i in range(0, 25):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        total += i
print(total)
```